# Looking for insight into a (presumed) MSVC 19.16 bug

Tags: c++

Proof of concept: https://godbolt.org/z/bbpxUB

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, std::size_t S = sizeof(T)>
using complete_t = T;

template <typename...>
struct is_complete_type : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_complete_type<complete_t<T>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename>
struct A;

template <>
struct A<int> {};

static_assert(is_complete_type<A<int>>::value);
static_assert(!is_complete_type<A<double>>::value);
```

MSVC 19.16

> (19): error C2607: static assertion failed
>
> Compiler returned: 2

I'm writing a type trait to determine if a given type is completely defined. The result is pretty simple and is based on the fact that types that aren't fully defined don't have a size.  It is useful for determining if a type has been specialized. It works on most compilers, but fails in MSVC 19.16. MSVC 19.20 and later seem to work as expected.

Does anyone have any insight on this (bug)? Is there an easy workaround that doesn't overcomplicate things too much?

Comment: Which assertion fails?

Comment: For reference, MSVC 19.16 compiler is Visual Studio 2017 with patch level 15.9 (the last patch for VS 2017).  MSVC 19.20 is Visual Studio 2019 16.0 (no patches).  Latest is 19.25 (VS 2019 with 16.5 patch).

Comment: It's the second assertion that fails.